# Streaming RS-232 Output to the browser

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

Is this possible? If so, what is the industry standard as far as software goes? Specifically, I am referring to .net controls.

Thank you

EDITED:
Here is what I need. I have a thin client with a balance where RS-232 is used to interact with the thin client. Currently, it is a compact framework app. What I would like to know id whether it is possible to have the same set up in a web application. So that would entail that the RS-232 is NOT the server RS-232 - it is the user's computer RS-232 - RS-232 is on the client. So when the RS-232 spits out input, it should go to the browser. Is it possible in a web application?

Comment: being a relatively obscure requirement, I doubt that there is anything very standardized about the process. if you could give some more details about what you want, I could probably offer some suggestions.

Comment: As you describe it, no; Sorry. The client machine needs to publish the buffer change to the server. The server needs to manage the list of subscribers to the data. the server need to return the right data to the client. A possible solution is to capture the entire state of the port and once it's complete, send it to the server and then you have a known start/end point which makes packetable dissemination possible.

Comment: It might help if you can describe your whole problem domain; this isn't an unusual problem in software development - it's just the web aspect that makes this a different question, if you can tell us about your problem 'domain' we might have a different idea that works.

Comment: Russ, make your second comment an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of;

- Buffer the serial data in an application object, and then use an ajax call triggered by a timer to grab and display the latest data.
- For shorter streams of data, you could, instead of using asp.net controls per se, do something like;

  ```
  Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
  Response.Clear();

  String serialData;

  while(serialData = getSerialData() {
     Response.Write(serialData);
     Response.Flush();
  }
  ```

  This will write text content to the web browser in real time.  You probably wouldn't want to keep this session open for too long though.

  If you wanted to display the stream of data within another page, then just place the page with the above code within an iFrame.

  Also note that the above would best be done in an ashx handler rather than an aspx page.

Comment: codekaizen has a good suggestion with using a HttpListener if you are building a standalone app.  You could combine the flushing technique I show with that to achieve the real time stream.

Comment: There's also a question of terminology, but Matt Tew has encapsulated what I wanted to answer: You're not easily going to stream this data to a client, certainly not without a custom server control and a custom client that subscribes to the custom control and does whatever it needs to do. I mention terminology because I'm not entirely clear if you want to push new RS-232 changes to the client or if a subscribe/act_on_changes model is appropriate

Comment: thanks, but how does this capture output from RS-232 client machine?

Comment: see my EDIT to the original question

Comment: Please see my comment to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can do it. You'd read from a [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) instance, and output it via an [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx).

The trick will be knowing what you want to do with the page that the `HttpListener` serves up. Since data will be coming in on the COM port in real time, you'll probably want to buffer it between HTTP requests to your server, since otherwise, if you try to read the port without data waiting, you'll hang the listener. You can also miss data if you don't read it regularly and it fills the `SerialPort` read buffer.

Comment: And you need to know that the buffer being requesting is the same one  the request asked for, and that it's synced ... its for whole reasons like this that .push wasnt a massive success!